# How to upload image with carrier-wave immediately after select in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, carrierwave

How can I upload the image file to server immediately after select the file with AJAX? Can anyone show me little example? The beginning is:

```
$('.choose_image').on('change', function(){
    // UPLOAD CODE HERE
})
```

with PHP I did:

```
$.ajax {
    url: 'some.php',
    method: 'POST'
}
```

but how it will be in Rails?

Covers Controller:

```
def create
    @cover = Cover.create(cover_params)

    if @cover.save
        redirect_to :back
    end
end

def cover_params
    params.require(:cover).permit(:image)
end
```

Cover model:

```
mount_uploader :image, CoverUploader
```

I want to upload file to server on select file. How can I do it?

Comment: Any one? Who can help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby solution is very similar to the PHP version.  The upload code stays the same and the ajax request needs to be modified for a rails app.

```
var formData = new FormData(),
    $input = $('#avatar');

formData.append('user[avatar]', $input[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: this.model.url(),
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  type: 'PUT'
});
```

Check out this [tutorial](http://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-upload-to-carrierwave-with-javascript) for more information.

Comment: no errors here. Just nothing happens. I update the question and add some details

Comment: So the log isn't showing a request hitting the webserver?

Comment: the log is empty. Nothing at the moment when I select the image